# Delete entity through hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have meet some issues trying to delete an entity in my project.

To explain the situation, I have two entities Parent and Child.

See the two classes below :

```
@Entity
private class Parent {
  private long id;

  @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
  private Map<Long, Child> children;

}

@Entity
private class Child {
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Parent parent;
}
```

I have tried with a parentDAO to delete one child entity.

```
Parent parent = this.parentDAO.findById(currParentId);
Child child = this.childDAO.findById(currChildId);
parent.getChildren().remove(child.getId());
parent.save()
```

I expect this code to work (remove the child from the parent list, and then save that will remove the orphan). In addition, all my code is annotated with @Transactional.

However I have an hibernate Exception : HibernateException: Unable to instantiate proxy instance.

Can you tell me why am I having this issue and how can I solved it ?

Comment: Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: What does `parent.save` do?